# Create a shallow copy without leaking memory and dangling pointer in C++

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, delete-operator, shallow-copy

Or is it not possible, and I have to do a deep copy.  Lets say I have an object `A`, and I want to make a shallow copy of `A` into `B`.  If I delete `A`, and `A` destroys all if its members, then `B` would have dangling pointers.  If `A` doesn't destroy its members, then `B`'s pointers are still good. However, if I delete `B`, then its members won't be destroyed when `B` gets destroyed, so I will leak memory.  Is there a way for an object to know when it has the only reference to memory, and delete it?  Or is this not possible, and I have to use a deep copy.

Comment: Use-case for `std::shared_ptr`  See: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr

Comment: Agreed, look at `std::shared_ptr`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way for an object to know when it has the only reference
>   to memory, and delete it?

Yes, it's called `std::shared_ptr`.

Comment: Is there a way to do this if I used c++98?

Comment: @Blubber Make design decisions on ownership and lifetime; this is not a coding issue but a design problem - how long should objects live for and who is responsible for them.  `std::shared_ptr` is a simple answer to _"I don't know"_ but often the problem can be designed away.

Comment: @RichardCritten: Exactly. In my experience, it's rare that `std::shared_ptr` is really the implementation of a robust design, especially since `std::unique_ptr` came along.